# How to Scroll vertically in one div and at the same time affecting another div that scrolls horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have 2 div, A and B, I need a way that when I scroll vertically in A, the div B also move at the same time in the Horizontal direction.

I searched and can't find a solution to this problem, and if possible, a solution without a framework.

[click here to see what I mean in on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYkHR.png)

```css
.content-up-down {
 background: pink;
 margin: auto;
 width : 400px;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content-1 {
 background: rgb(250,230,230);
 padding : 32px;
 margin: 16px;
}

.content-left-right {
 background: rgb(200,250,200);
 margin: auto;
 margin-top:32px;
 padding-top: 16px;
 
 width : 400px;
 height: 96px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrap-content-2 {
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.content-2 {
 background: rgb(100,255,150);
 display: inline-block;
 width:64px;
 height: 64px;
 margin:0px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-up-down">
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div>
   <div class="content-1"> </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="content-left-right">
   <div class="wrap-content-2">
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
    <div class="content-2"> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to do it by JavaScript. Basically, you add an EventListener to one of your containers, detecting scrolling events. Then you simulate the others container scroll.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you would need to listen for scrolling on the pink div using jQuery. Here's a rough estimate:

```js
$(".pink").scroll(function() {
  $(".green").scrollLeft(($(".pink").scrollTop() / $(".pink").height()) * $(".green").width());
});
```

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
 }

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pink">
 a
 <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
  <br>
  d
  <br>
  a
  <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
  <br>
  d
  <br>
  a
  <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
  <br>
  d
  <br>
  a
  <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
  <br>
  d
  <br>
  a
  <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
  <br>
  d
  <br>
</div>

<div class="green">   efghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghefghef
</div>
```

Hope the code makes enough sense.

Comment: I'm still trying to make it without Jquery, if I can't, I'll use your code, thank you.